# How to set the google analytics opt-out cookie for sub-domains

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics

I am setting the google opt-out cookie as described here and the ga-disable cookie is set.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#disable

Unfortunately the cookie is set for /example.com only and on any subdomains like xy.example.com the ga-disable cookie is not recognized.

I would like the opt-out of the cookie to be valid on all the subdomains.
 
How to I accomplish this ? 
 
The code that is running and setting the Google opt-out cookie:

```js
// Set to the same value as the web property used on the site
var gaProperty = 'UA-yyyyyy';

// Disable tracking if the opt-out cookie exists.
var disableStr = 'ga-disable-' + gaProperty;
if (document.cookie.indexOf(disableStr + '=true') > -1) {
  window[disableStr] = true;
}

// Opt-out function
function gaOptout() {
  document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
    window[disableStr] = true;
}
</script>
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The domain needed to be set as `domain=.example.com;`
Important is the leading dot that makes the opt-out cookie work on all subdomains.

```js
// Opt-out function
function gaOptout() {
  document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; domain=.example.com; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
  window[disableStr] = true;
}
```